# Access violation exception in downcasting

Tags: c++, exception, access-violation, downcast

When doing the following downcast, I am getting an access violation exception. I cannot understand why.

```
ExpressDataSet * data_set;
data_set = dynamic_cast<ExpressDataSet *>(reader.getExpressDataSet());
```

The method getExpressDataSet of reader is defined as follows:

```
virtual BaseExpressDataSet * getExpressDataSet();
```

The relationships between involved classes are as follows:

```
class BaseExpressDataSet
{
};

class ExpressDataSet : public BaseExpressDataSet
{
}
```

I think all the needed info are now provided. I hope you could help me clarifying this issue.

Comment: I think the definition of getExpressDataSet() would be more helpful than just the declaration.  A dynamic_cast on a null pointer or on a dangling pointer could cause an access violation exception, but how are we to know?

Comment: Do you get the access violation on the `dynamic_cast` line? If so, try the `reader.getExpressDataSet()` on a separate line and see if that is the problem or the `dynamic_cast`. If not and it happens when you use `data_set`, did you check for `nullptr`?

Comment: Does the violation come from the posted code? Or from an attempt to use `data_set` afterwards (possibly because the cast failed and gave a null pointer)? Does `getExpressDataSet` return a pointer to a valid object? Is that object an `ExpressDataSet`? Could you post a complete (but minimal) test case to demonstrate the problem, so we don't have to guess what your code might be doing?

Comment: @stefaanv thanks for your answer, but I do not have the definition of the method getExpressDataSet(), because it is part of library I am only using, and that I have not developed. Anyway, I have tried to do auto p = reader.getExpressDataSet(), to check what is returned, and the returned pointer was not null. In case of dangling pointer, how can it affect the dynamic_cast so to make it throw an access violation exception???? Given what explained here above, I confirm that the exception is thrown by the dynamic_cast. Moreover, no actions later on the data_set variable are performed.

Comment: If you are using a shared library, this might be relevant: https://gcc.gnu.org/faq.html#dso

Comment: @RomanL thanks but the third-party library is linked statically, I am using the .lib files

Comment: Solved: simply the object on which I was working was null. Sorry for having bothered all of you for such a stupid issue.